# Parcel Owner to see only his parcel in map application

Tags: arcpy, sql, arcgis-platform, publishing

How can i create a map where user can only see his parcel. parcel are defined has one unique ID. I have Arcgis online Server and Desktop Advanced license.
the map to be published in a web application which will show owners details reading from SQL server database.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Have you been able to draw your parcels in ArcMap as the first step of authoring a map to publish?  If so, can you [edit] that into your question so that we can get a better idea of precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to have a column corresponding to the Parcel unique ID named for example "UniquePin". In that column generate a 4 or 6 digit pin numbers. And make sure no pin is repeated.

Make a definition query  `"UniquePin" = {0}.format(pin)`, where pin = a 4-6 digit number <- this is a python example use an SQL equivalent.

In this scenario the client provides the pin you distributed, in order to retrieve the parcel information. The extra column allows you to change pins regularly without a need to affect the unique parcel ID in case of a security breach or if people forgot their pins or want to change them.